# How to "append" to personalised ROS array message in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ros

I defined the two following message structures for a ROS package:

point.msg

```
float64 x
float64 y
```

points.msg

```
point[] points
```

I am instantiating and filling a points array in Python as follows:

```
point_list = points()
pt = point()
for element in self.points:
     pt.x = element[0,0]
     pt.y = element[1,0]
     point_list += (pt,)
```

And this is the error I am getting:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'points' and 'tuple'
```

PS : tried `.append` and it is still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message `points` is not directly a list of `point` messages, but a structure, that has a member called `points` which is a list.

To add elements to this list, you have to access the member, not the containing structure:

```
point_list.points.append(pt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
point_list = []
pt = point()
for element in self.points:
     pt.x = element[0,0]
     pt.y = element[1,0]
     point_list += (pt,)
```

Before you were telling the compiler the point class was a list object which is not possible unless you call a method of point. By setting it to a generic list (`[]`) it can take any type. That's part of the beauty of python, you dont always need to specify object type.